# How to filter Jira issues by more complex criteria, like " status changed to Reopened"?

Tags: json, jira, jira-rest-api

Here's what I do:
I'm sending basic JQL (Like SQL - bug for Jira) query through Rest API, and parsing the resulting json, for example:

```
Jira.aligntech.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=filter = 24808 AND priority in (Blocker, Critical)
```

I'm deserializing the resulting Json, and than working with it to figure out various statistics. I'm doing it using C#
Some filtering is pretty easy, for example finding all issues that are resolved, etc
But i've stumbled upon some filtering requirements that I don't know hot to implement using the Json from Jira:
for example I want to do something quivalent to: 
AND status changed to Reopened
When I'm looking at the Json, on the part that is responsible for Status, it is this part:

```
"status": {
                "self": "https://jira.aligntech.com/rest/api/2/status/6",
                "description": "The issue is considered finished, the resolution is correct. Issues which are closed can be reopened.",
                "iconUrl": "https://jira.aligntech.com/images/icons/statuses/generic.png",
                "name": "Closed",
                "id": "6",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://jira.aligntech.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
                    "id": 3,
                    "key": "done",
                    "colorName": "green",
                    "name": "Done"
                }
            },
```

Is there any way i could could filter the Issues by "status changed to XXX" using this info in Json?
If no, please point me to some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You want to search issue history. [This](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-5536?focusedCommentId=534891&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-534891) may help.